# video not playing through MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

I am very new to IOS app development , I am trying to play a video from gallery through MPMoviePlayer. I have list of all the video's urls in an array, but when trying to play the video MPMoviePlayer launches but does not play any video. Here is the code that I am using:

```
 NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[urlArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

playMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[self.view addSubview:playMovie.view];

 playMovie.fullscreen = YES;

 [playMovie play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code from apple documentation, I think you are not using **[player prepareToPlay]**, which **Prepares the  player for playback by preloading its buffers**. rest all looks fine.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match    parent's
[myView addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play]
```

Comment: Hi, Omer adding  [player prepareToPlay]; has agin the same response , music player with black screen this is the url i am passing  "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=C75C9040-0DBE-4B16-8716-8A31AAAD28EF&ext=MOV"